# Error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Code creates some PDFs with ExportAsFixedFormat but then errors out

Tags: excel, vb.net, pdf, visual-studio-2017

My VB.Net program in Visual Studio creates Excel files and then saves them as PDF but after so many(30, 40 or whatever, not the point) it errors out saying "Error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'".
Probably I am thinking it is the way Excel gets closed/released?
The error is from this line of code after I open an Excel document and try to save it as PDF. Again, that always happens after some documents have been already saved as PDF(sometimes 30, sometimes 50...):

```
xwb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, "\\ken-resourcesan\fileshares\fieldshare\IT\nsantagata\ARStatements_CustomerInvoicesPDF\" & originalCustomerName & " " & customerNumber & " " & todaysDate & ".pdf")
```

Here is the whole code I have:

**THIS CREATES THE EXCEL DOCUMENT AND FILLS IT WITH DATA:**

```
Public Sub PopulateSheet(ByVal dt As Data.DataTable, ByVal File As String)
        Dim oXL As Excel.Application = CType(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
        Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim oRng As Excel.Range
        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add
        oSheet = CType(oWB.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)

'****Spreadsheet gets populated
......

'****Then
oWB.SaveAs(File)

oRng = Nothing
oXL.Quit()

GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oXL)
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oSheet)
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oWB)

oSheet = Nothing
oWB = Nothing
oXL = Nothing
```

**FINALLY THIS SAVES THE DOCUMENT AS PDF:**

```
Dim xl As Object
Dim xwb As Object
xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

dt = CreateTable()

PopulateSheet(dt, "\\ken-resourcesan\fileshares\fieldshare\IT\nsantagata\ARStatements_CustomerInvoicesExcel\" & originalCustomerName & " " & customerNumber & " " & todaysDate & ".xlsx")

'****Open xlsx doc to save as pdf
xwb = xl.Workbooks.Open("\\ken-resourcesan\fileshares\fieldshare\IT\nsantagata\ARStatements_CustomerInvoicesExcel\" & originalCustomerName & " " & customerNumber & " " & todaysDate & ".xlsx")

xwb.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = False
xwb.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
xwb.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False

'****Save as pdf
xwb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, "\\ken-resourcesan\fileshares\fieldshare\IT\nsantagata\ARStatements_CustomerInvoicesPDF\" & originalCustomerName & " " & customerNumber & " " & todaysDate & ".pdf")

xl.Quit()
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xl)
xl = Nothing
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xwb)
xwb = Nothing
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Any help highly appreciated.  Thank you

********COMMENT:** I feel there is a problem with how Excel gets released/closed at the end of the two Excel processes. I thought that because the program runs fine and saves the Excel files as PDF, but every time it never creates all the files.  It stops after a number of PDF files get created at the line where there is "ExportAsFixedFormat". It never stops at the same specific file, so I would say there isn't a problem with any specific PDF.

Comment: I feel there is a problem with how Excel gets released/closed at the end of the two Excel processes. I thought that because the program runs fine and saves the Excel files as PDF, but every time it never creates all the files.  It stops after a number of PDF files get created at the line where there is "ExportAsFixedFormat". It never stops at the same specific file, so I would say there isn't a problem with any specific PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mainly changed "ExportAsFixedFormat" with "Printout" and now it seems to be working fine.  Thanks to all for your help!

THIS IS THE CODE i HAVE NOW:

```
Dim Path As String = "\\ken-resourcesan\fileshares\fieldshare\IT\nsantagata\ARStatements_CustomerInvoicesExcel\" & originalCustomerName & " " & customerNumber & " 050720.xlsx"
                Dim Excel As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
                Dim WorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Path)
                Dim WorkSheets As Excel.Sheets = WorkBook.Sheets
                Dim WorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(WorkSheets(1), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
                Excel.DisplayAlerts = False
                Excel.Visible = False
                'SAVE AS PDF
                Dim totalFileName As String = "\\ken-resourcesan\fileshares\fieldshare\IT\nsantagata\ARStatements_CustomerInvoicesPDF\" & originalCustomerName & " " & customerNumber & " " & todaysDate & ".pdf"
                Excel.ActiveSheet.Printout(Copies:=1, Preview:=False, ActivePrinter:="Microsoft Print to PDF", PrintToFile:=True, Collate:=True, PrToFileName:=totalFileName, IgnorePrintAreas:=False)
```